# create a button that shows or hides a div depending on whether it is currently showing

Tags: javascript

I'm fairly new in with JS and was wondering, if 
there is a more cleaner way of writing this code?

I'm trying to create a button that shows or hides a div depending on whether it is currently showing.

Many Thanks in Advance

Anne

```
var button = document.getElementById('button');
var hideText = document.getElementById('output').className = 'hide';

button.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
    if(hideText){
        document.getElementById('output').className = 'unhide';
        hideText = false;
    }else{
        document.getElementById('output').className = 'hide';
        hideText = true;
    }
})
```

CSS

```
.hide{display: none;}

.unhide{display: block;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a single class (e.g. `unhide`) and make it invisible by default. Then do

```
button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    document.getElementById('output').classList.toggle('unhide');
}
```

Comment: Thank you all so much, I really appreciate all the suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

You can just toggle the classes

```
button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    document.getElementById('output').classList.toggle('hide');
}
```

Comment: *`unhide`* class seem useless!?

Comment: @F.Hauri Yes, I think you're right. (Removed it per your suggestion)

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the extra variable `hideText` and also the extra css if you implement like this

```
var x = document.getElementById("output");
if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
} else {
    x.style.display = "none";
}
```

In jquery the are other simpler possible way like `toggle`, `hide`, `show`.